# File .ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this on Microsoft Azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I am receiving the following error when trying to deploy a solution from GitHub to Microsoft Azure through a Azre VM.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo

From my understanding at some point during the deployment, the predocs.ps1 should be executed. But unfortunately this is not possible due the following error:

```
./scripts/loadenv.ps1: C:\dev\azure\ai\azure-search-openai-demo-main\scripts\prepdocs.ps1:1
Line |
   1 |  ./scripts/loadenv.ps1
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | File C:\dev\azure\ai\azure-search-openai-demo-main\scripts\loadenv.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
     | C:\dev\azure\ai\azure-search-openai-demo-main\scripts\loadenv.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this
     | script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see
     | about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
Installing dependencies from "requirements.txt" into virtual environment
Start-Process: C:\dev\azure\ai\azure-search-openai-demo-main\scripts\prepdocs.ps1:10
Line |
  10 |  Start-Process -FilePath $venvPythonPath -ArgumentList "-m pip install …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
Running "prepdocs.py"
Start-Process: C:\dev\azure\ai\azure-search-openai-demo-main\scripts\prepdocs.ps1:41
Line |
  41 |  Start-Process -FilePath $venvPythonPath -ArgumentList $argumentList - …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried to change the Execution Policy on the VM:

```
PS C:\Users\bog> get-executionpolicy -list

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy          Bypass
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

And when i change it to Unrestricted on all Scopes, i receive the following error:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by
a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
execution policy of Bypass. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more
information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

I have no more ideas how to solve this. Any ideas out there?

Comment: Try to run powershell script using bypass option, f.e.: `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File .\scripts\loadenv.ps1`

Comment: I have run in environment make sure to give path of loadenv.ps1 and prepdocs.ps1 like this-> `C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\azure-search-openai-demo-main\azure-search-openai-demo-main\scripts\loadenv.ps1 C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\azure-search-openai-demo-main\azure-search-openai-demo-main\scripts\prepdocs.ps1` [output](https://i.imgur.com/jDkZmb9.png)